# triple intersections inside regular n-gon, n odd.

Tags: geometry

Suppose one has a regular $n$ gon inscribed in the unit circle, where $n\ge 7$ is odd. One can take the vertices as the $n$th roots of unity, say.

Then if $A,B,C,D,E,F$ are six of the vertices, a natural question is whether there are choices of these vertices for which the three line segments (chords) $AB,CD,EF$ meet at some point inside the circle. Naturally in setting this up to ask it, one assumes no two of the chords are parallel.

An answer yes or no (with example or proof) would be appreciated, or even a reference to this question. A related question occurs if we replace the chords by the entire lines, such as line $AB.$ This means we allow the meeting point to be outside the circle. (I guess this version becomes trivial if one of our points is actually *on* the circle.)

Please note: I'm not in town much lately and so might not respond in a timely manner to any answers, but still will appreciate them.

I found e.g. for even $n=8$ there are triple intersections not at the origin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For odd $n$ there are no triple intersections.  The number of intersections is given in [OEIS A006561](http://oeis.org/A006561) with the formula for odd $n$ being $(n^4-6n^3+11n^2-6n)/24$ which is the number of ways to select four points out of $n$.  A paper by B. Poonen and M. Rubinstein that calculates the number of points for all $n$ is found [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/9508209.pdf)

Comment: Good (and complete) answer! (+1, accept.)